Prove that a Jordan measurable set A can be approximated arbitrarily close by a compact set K

Definition (Jordan Measure): A bounded set $A \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ is said to be Jordan measurable if $v(A) = \int_A \mathbb{1}_A$ exists, and we call $v(A)$ the volume of $A$.


Definition (Jordan Measure Zero, JMZ): A bounded set is said to have Jordan measure zero if it is Jordan measurable and $v(A) = 0$. It follows that a bounded set $A$ has Jordan measure zero if $\forall \epsilon > 0$, $\exists$ finite collection of closed rectangles $V_1, ..., V_N$ s.t. $\bigcup_{i=1}^N V_i \supset A$ and $\sum_{i=1}^N v(V_i) < \epsilon$.

Let $A \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ be an open bounded set that is Jordan measurable, $v(A) > 0$, and assume the boundary $\partial A$ has JMZ (stronger than Lebesgue measure zero, which is implied by the Jordan measurability of A). I want to prove that $A$ can be approximated arbitrary close by a compact set $K \subset A$.
Here is my attempt:
Let $A \subset S$, S be a closed rectangle. By that $\partial A$ has JMZ, $\forall \epsilon > 0$, $\exists V_1, ..., V_N$ finite collection of closed rectangles s.t. $\bigcup_{i=1}^N V_i \supset \partial A$ and $\sum_{i=1}^N v(V_i) < \epsilon/2$. Denote the total area of boundaries of $V_1,..., V_N$ by $T$, and let $V = \bigcup_{i=1}^N V_i$.
Let $P = \{I_k\}$ be a partition of S into cubes, $I_k$ are closed cubes with side length $\delta$. Then
$$\sum_{I_k \in P,\; I_k \cap V \neq \emptyset} v(I_k) \leq \frac{T}{\delta^{n-1}} * \delta^n + \sum_{i=1}^N v(V_i) < T\delta + \epsilon/2$$
Because there are at most $\frac{T}{\delta^{n-1}}$ cubes that can intersect with the boundary of $V$, and the volume of each cube is $\delta^n$. Make $\delta$ small enough so that the total is less than $\epsilon$.
Define $K = \bigcup_{I_k \in P, \; I_k \subset A} I_k$, a compact set inside $A$. Then,
$$v(A) - v(K) = \int_A 1 - \int_K 1 = \int_{A\setminus K} 1 \leq \sum_{I_k \in P,\; I_k\cap \partial A \neq \emptyset} v(I_k) \leq \sum_{I_k \in P,\; I_k\cap V \neq \emptyset} v(I_k) <\epsilon$$
So K is compact subset of A with volume that can be made arbitrarily close to $A$.
Is my argument about the maximum volumes of cubes that intersect with $\partial A$ correct? Does the proof makes sense? If so, how do i relieve the assumption that $\partial A$ has JMZ to only Lebesgue measure zero?
Thank you.
Edit: This is a duplicate question to Compact $C \subset$ Jordan-measurable $A$ such that $\int_{A-C} 1 < \epsilon$.
However, I want K to be union fo cubes of the same side length rather than rectangles.
